# httpclient returns response of the login page and not the requested page but returns 200 ok as the status code

Tags: java, httpclient, autologin

I have a java class which attempts to autologin to a website. The status code shows 200 OK and I read the 200OK is for successful HTTP requests and In a POST request that I use, the response will contain an entity describing or containing the result of the action.

But the response I get is still the html of the signin page not the logged in page. This tells me that I'm not successfully logged in.

What are the possibilities for this to go wrong?

Comment: Not enough information to help. Show what you're doing.

Comment: If the request is processed using a defined processing sequence, even if it's unexpected, it can return HTTP 200. It does not mean "your success" but "a request answered with no abnormal events happening".

Comment: I have updated the code, any inputs?

Comment: If that is your code, does the site expect the password parameter to have three s? (passswd)

Comment: oh no. its passwd. Thanks for pointing out. I think now i get a location to redirect to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do you store the cookies you receive after submitting the login form?
- Do you provide these cookies in your next requests?
- Are you sure that the login page does not send you a redirect to a certain 'confirmation' URL? And if it does, do you follow it?

Open Firefox, install LiveHTTPHeaders extension, record the login process inside the browser, make sure you can correctly replay it.